# How to compare multiple column with multiple field array in Select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get stuck a bit at query creation at API server, I just want to respond with modified tracks data. I have `tracks` table with few columns like this.

`tracks(id, audio_fingerprint, name, creation_date, modified_date)`

Now I just want tracks which are updated after it's last fetched timestamp (Array of audio fingerprint and last fetched timestamp passed as API request parameter).

`SELECT * from tracks WHERE (audio_fingerprint, modified_date) IN (Array(audioFingerprint, > lastFetchedTimestamp));`

(^^ It is invalid query, just used for understanding).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table tracks (audio_fingerprint text, modified_date date);
insert into tracks values
    ('a', '2017-01-10'),
    ('b', '2017-01-10'),
    ('a', '2017-02-10'),
    ('b', '2017-02-10'),
    ('c', '2017-02-01');
```

Place your arguments in a `with` query and join it with your table:

```
with given_values (fingerprint, last_fetched) as (
values
    ('a', '2017-01-01'::date),
    ('b', '2017-02-01')
)

select * 
from tracks t
join given_values v
on t.audio_fingerprint = v.fingerprint
and t.modified_date > v.last_fetched;

 audio_fingerprint | modified_date | fingerprint | last_fetched 
-------------------+---------------+-------------+--------------
 a                 | 2017-01-10    | a           | 2017-01-01
 a                 | 2017-02-10    | a           | 2017-01-01
 b                 | 2017-02-10    | b           | 2017-02-01
(3 rows)
```

---

Instead of CTE you can also use a derived table:

```
select * 
from tracks t
join (
    values
        ('a', '2017-01-01'::date),
        ('b', '2017-02-01')
    ) v(fingerprint, last_fetched)
on t.audio_fingerprint = v.fingerprint
and t.modified_date > v.last_fetched;
```

Comment: It's working in psql but still not getting how to set audio_fingerprint and modified_date data list from java to psql statement. checking out about it...

Comment: Using `WITH (CTE)` with jpa native query giving token error at `with`. I have many dependent tables are on tracks table, those data also need to be loaded with track data. Any idea how to manage it?

Comment: Here is the issue detail: Getting NoViableAltException: unexpected token: WITH with JPA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567017/getting-noviablealtexception-unexpected-token-with-with-jpa

Comment: `JPA does not support sub-selects/derived table in the FROM clause` (as I got in on SO reply), I have around 5-7 dependent table with multi-level dependency. Is there any good alternative to it?

Comment: Using `Native query` we can resolve this issue but then I need to use `SqlResultSetMapping` for each Entity, fields and it's dependent entity. Bit lengthy and complex too for later changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never used JPA. It's really surprising that it doesn't support the basic SQL features like cte or derived tables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [LEAD or LAG](http://fle.github.io/detect-value-changes-between-successive-lines-with-postgresql.html) can help you?