# Getting NoViableAltException: unexpected token: WITH with JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, dropwizard

I am using [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531982/how-to-compare-multiple-column-with-multiple-field-array-in-select-query) given by @klin in my last question as below.

```
with given_values (fingerprint, last_fetched) as (
values
    ('a', '2017-01-01'::date),
    ('b', '2017-02-01')
)

select * 
from tracks t
join given_values v
on t.audio_fingerprint = v.fingerprint
and t.modified_date > v.last_fetched;
```

I am using JPA and Hibernate with Dropwizard. I am having Entity hierarchy like this.

- Track can have one or more

  - Structure
  - CueMarker
  - Transition
  - Genre

Want to load Track and it's child entities data, for that, I tried NamedQuery/NamedNativeQuery but it's giving me token error as like this.

```
web_1               | ERROR [2017-06-14 19:30:31,274] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:1: unexpected token: WITH
web_1               | ERROR [2017-06-14 19:30:31,288] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 1:1: unexpected token: WITH
web_1               | ! antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: WITH
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:191) ~[app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295) ~[app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) ~[app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126) [app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88) [app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190) [app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) [app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) [app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
web_1               | ! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800) [app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
```

Thanks